# Linux usb live cd not starting due to secure boot error

Tags: boot, grub, uefi, secure-boot

Greeting to you all, I'm having the following issue.

I've received a notebook (acer Aspire 3 A315-23) and
I'm trying to install a linux distribution on the system (namely a devuan beowulf).
I created a usb-live cd boot the laptop doesn't boot from usb drive and from the uefi-setup
I'm able to select the usb-pen drive as a bootable device, therefore I'm assuming that
the efi-partion is well set and correctly detected from the uefi-firmware.
Nevertheless after I select the pen-drive for booting the computer is unable to boot
and it outputs a (irony)very informative error message(/irony), namely "secure boot error".

Since both the grub-efi-application and the linux kernel should be signed with Microsoft's key
I'm a little bit lost on why the pen-drive cannot be booted.
Is there any particular reason on why it does work?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: _"Since both the grub-efi-application and the linux kernel should be signed with Microsoft's key"_ - should they? Signing a binary with Microsoft's key costs $100 per binary IIRC and there are some licensing issues. Some distros use an intermediate bootloader that they sign only once and use to chainload something signed by them. Others don't care. Signing the kernel would get expensive very quickly.

Comment: Why are you not disabling Secure Boot in the BIOS? Note that, depending on the Linux distribution installation, this might mean that you will always need to disable Secure Boot before booting it.

Comment: First of all, thanks for you replies, I wasn't expecting replies so soon. Now @gronostajgro according to [this](https://wiki.debian.org/UEFI#UEFI_Secure_Boot) debian (and therefore I suspect all its main derivates) should support secure boot. .

Comment: @harrymc thank you as well for your fast reply. Unfortunately it isn't my laptop, so before taking any action I would need the owner's approval, second  I'm really interested more in understanding why it's not secure booting rather than how to install the system

Comment: Debian is using the [shim](https://wiki.debian.org/SecureBoot#Shim) that I've mentioned. It's a first-stage bootloader that was signed just once to avoid the need to pay MS on every update. The next stage (kernel, GRUB, systemd-boot, whatever) can then be signed with Debian's private key which is verified by the shim.

Comment: @gronostajg but do the livecds not use shim? Is this the reason why livecds do not work with secure boot enabled?

Comment: Some do, some don't. $100 to sign a binary is more than some distros are willing to spend, so they decide that they don't care and you have to disable secure boot. Others (big players like Debian or Ubuntu) have decided to pay to have their shim signed so that their users don't have to tweak UEFI settings. It's purely a convenience thing - if anyone can sign anything for $100 then secure boot offers no extra security in the default configuration. (you can configure UEFI to not trust the "paid" signing keys though)